# Parse UTC offset from string to datetime in Google App Engine Python runtime

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, strptime

I want to parse a POST parameter like 2012-10-12T16:55+0300 to a `datetime` type in order to store it in `ndb.DateTimeProperty()` of my model.

Thus, what I have is:

```
from datetime import datetime
.....
my_date = datetime.strptime(self.request.get('my_date'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z')
```

This call generates the following error:

> ERROR    2012-10-12 14:03:08,376 webapp2.py:1553] 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z'

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I have read various posts but none of them helped me on this.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems someone filed a bug for the issue you see, which was rejected (see [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue6641)). In short, %z is not always supported. Quoting from the bug report:

> "Only the directives specified in the documentation [of
>   time.strftime()] are supported. Because strftime() is implemented per
>   platform it can sometimes offer more directives than those listed. But
>   strptime() is independent of any platform and thus does not
>   necessarily support all directives available that are not documented
>   as supported."

Comment: I have read this, but this basically says that it is dependent on the platform. So, the question is if the GAE environment supports it and if not, what is the solution to this problem.

Comment: @ThanosMakris You should add information of your environment in your original post. Also, the fact that you get the error indicates that the directive isn't supported, does it not?